# share existing tmux session

Tags: tmux

I have a tmux session already running. I have created it just with

```
tmux
```

now I can leave the session and re-enter with

```
tmux a -t 0
```

how can I share this session with other users? Usually one has to create the session with `-S` option, but I haven't. Is there a way to share my session?

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/2523/what-are-other-ways-to-share-a-tmux-session-between-two-users

Answer (score 5):

You can use [tmux](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi/OpenBSD-current/man1/tmux.1?query=tmux&sec=1) grouped session.

First, create initial session, change its name to `share`:

```
$ tmux
$ tmux list-session
0: 1 windows (created Wed Aug 27 00:14:05 2014) [80x23] (attached)   
$ tmux rename-session -t 0 share 
$ tmux list-session
share: 1 windows (created Wed Aug 27 00:14:05 2014) [80x23] (attached)
```

Then, from other client, you simply add `-t` option and grouped session name (in this example, it's `share`) to `tmux new-session` command:

```
$ tmux new-session -t share -s cuonglm
```

`-s` option set the session name. If other user, i.e wiso, want to attach grouped session, he simply do:

```
$ tmux new-session -t share -s wiso
```

From `man tmux`:

> If -t is given, the new session is grouped with target-session. This
>   means they share the same set of windows - all windows from
>   target-session are linked to the new session and any subsequent new
>   windows or windows being closed are applied to both sessions. The
>   current and previous window and any session options remain independent
>   and either session may be killed without affecting the other. Giving
>   -n or shell-command are invalid if -t is used.

Comment: `session not found: share`. How the new user should find the session of the first user?

Comment: @wiso: You must make an initial session, by typing `tmux`. Default session name `0`. Other user can type `tmux list-session` to list all sessions.

Comment: the other user don't see the sessions of the first user. `tmux; su; tmux list-sessions` -> `failed to connect to server`

Comment: @wiso: failed to connect to server meaning you have not started tmux yet.

Comment: the main user started a tmux session. Now root want to join the session of the main user.

Comment: @wiso: It does not matter root or any user. Do you follow my example and it works?

Comment: `tmux;` (control B + d to exit from tmux); `tmux rename-session -t 3 share2; su;` (enter root password) `tmux new-session -t share2 -s wiso` -> `session not found: share2`

Comment: @wiso: What is 3? tmux default sesssion is 0. And it seems that you have quited `tmux`, so the session does not exist anymore. After type `tmux`, type `tmux list-session` to get the session name(default to 0). Then join tmux session group in other terminal.

Comment: 3 because I have other 2 sessions. No, I haven't quitted tmux, as I have said I've done control+b d, which [detach] the session, doesn't close it.

Comment: @wiso: So I think it must be 2 because default tmux session name start at 0. You should try tmux list-session to obtain the right name.

Comment: sorry, I have 3 sessions. It's not this the point. 3 is correct, I have checked with tmux ls. The point is that the second (linux) user do not see the sessions of the first user.