# How can I use screen for training and/or remote assistance?

Tags: ssh, gnu-screen

So, in theory I can log in as an admin user and have someone else log in as the same user or a different user over an SSH session and have both users attached to the same screen. In our case we have a rather complex environment setup and sometimes need remote assistance with it. How is this done? Do we both need to be the same user?

Answer (score 1):

I understand you are aimed at an application for training, and although your question specifically states *screen*, let me suggest *tmux*.

With *tmux* you can create sessions, to which you can connect from several computers. I have only done it for the same user, so I do not know if it is possible to attach to sessions created by a different user.

You can have even several sessions on the same machine. For example, you may run the following command to create a new session. Run it with the same user your pupil is going to use. You can name the session whatever you want (I chose *lesson01*).

```
$ tmux new-session -s lesson01
```

Then, your padawan logs onto your machine over SSH using the same user as before. He may then run this command to attach to your session.

```
$ tmux attach-session -t lesson01
```

Whatever you time in one terminal, should automatically appear on the other. Also, with *tmux* you split the terminal in two (leaving one for you, and the other for your pupil).

I hope you find this useful for education and training purposes. Again, sorry not to answer how it is done with *screen*.

Comment: The idea if fine, for training or education purposes I would rather much prefer that the trainee is with a less privilege user.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro I searched stackexchange and found this. I hope you find it useful. http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/2523/what-are-other-ways-to-share-a-tmux-session-between-two-users

Answer (score 1):

An alternative approach to redirect the output of your terminal to a terminal of some other user is:

Doing at your terminal:

```
mkfifo foo; script -f foo
```

Use the who command to see the terminal of the other user; and on another terminal of yours, redirect the output to the terminal of the other user, as root:

```
cat foo >> /dev/pts/2
```