# How to reload tmux window in faster way

Tags: tmux

I don't have root in the OS and sometimes `t` or `tt` can reload old tmux window. But I wonder how to find how many tmux sessions in OS and reload it in faster way?

```
xx@bsa0483:~$ t ls
0: 3 windows (created Sat Jun 30 14:23:58 2018) [129x34]

xx@bsa0483:~$ tmux ls
server not found: No such file or directory
```

But previously, `tmux ls` worked on the OS:

```
xx@bsa0248:~$ tmux ls
0: 3 windows (created Sun Jun 10 16:39:33 2018) [123x32]
1: 3 windows (created Sun Jun 10 16:43:10 2018) [123x32]
2: 3 windows (created Sun Jun 10 17:14:23 2018) [98x29]
```

Related setting for the tmux is in below picture:
[image]

Comment: What is "t" exactly?

Comment: Related - https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/2523/what-are-other-ways-to-share-a-tmux-session-between-two-users. I suspect you cannot see other user's `tmux` sessions without having elevated priv., such as root, to do so.

Comment: I don't want to see other's tmux session, I need to know my tmux session so that I can reload it in needing.